# what is the difference between the big and the biggest?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

As I know we use superlative form after the article **the**.
In that case, big should become **the biggest**. However, I have seen some people are writing the big (without superlative) willy nilly. Couldn't find any explanations out there.

For instance:
[image: Example]

Comment: Why do you think that "the big" is not allowed?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I am preparing for CPE. That is why I have to be precise. I don't know if you can substitute biggest with big. I am not saying it not allowed. I want to know if it is grammatically correct.

Comment: ELL isn't really a place to wonder about random hypothetical situations. You seem to be asking about the following structure: definite article + adjective in absolute form + noun ("the smart dog", "the fast car", "the expensive television", etc.). That is covered in many elementary English grammar guides. If their explanation confuses you for some reason, then ELL is a good resource to clarify such issues.

Comment: I think I  have failed to make you understand. I was asking if big can be replaced with biggest in some situations. For instance, instead of writing the biggest difference between.... can we write the biggest difference between....

Comment: Oh, I think that I understand now. (I think that one instance of "biggest" should have been "big" in your last sentence.) Yes, we write "big" if the meaning is not comparative or superlative, and we write "biggest" if the meaning is superlative. That is what the absolute and superlative forms are for. Either one can go between "the" and a noun.

Comment: I am pretty sure that in conversation 'the big difference between X and Y' really means 'the most significant difference [in my opinion] between X and Y' and is thus superlative really.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't know it is correct. But what I perceive is that the big difference is a significant difference or could be one of the biggest differences (assuming there are multiple big differences). The biggest difference is surely superlative. (The most superior one. There is no bigger than the biggest.) . Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ghost  I believe that '**the** main difference' and '**the** big difference' can both mean the same as 'the biggest difference'. Note the use of the definite article ('the').

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It seems obvious sometimes.  But, to be god precise, I was trying to draw a line between these two fellows.

Comment: "The big dog came into my garden." "I bought the big car." "I like the big jacket." "The big mountain is Denali." All completely standard uses of the+big+noun.

Answer (score 1):

Using the superlative after **the** will certainly be correct in many cases, but not always.

Suppose I'm in the market for a new home, and have been looking at some possible choices. I might say this:

1. The biggest difference between those two houses was the price.

This would mean that there were several differences, some of them even big differences, but the biggest difference of all was the price. Sentence 1 ranks the differences.

But I might also say this:

2. The big difference between those two houses was the price.

Now I'm saying that there may be several differences, some big, some small, but I'm not ranking them. Instead I'm filtering them. Of all the differences that we could discuss, that's the one that matters to me. It's the big one.

The difference between sentence 1 and sentence 2 is subtle, but it is there. We can see it more clearly if we add a third sentence:

3. The two big differences between the houses were the price and the views over the beach.

Now the filtering process has identified two differences that can be labelled big. The issue is not which is biggest. The issue is that now the set of differences big enough to matter has two items in it.

Answer (score 0):

Compare with "The big bang theory", "The big man on campus", "The big boss", "The big picture", "The big Lebowski", "The big city", etc.

It's more of a title applied to something *without* making an explicit comparison; someone or something that is obvious without having to look for it.

So, "the big difference" would be a difference so blatant that one doesn't even need to consider whether there are any other differences.

Comment: "the Big Bang theory" is a theory about a Big Bang, not a big theory.